# how can change the color of parent link while selecting dropdown

Tags: css

Pls check my Js fiddle , i couldn't make highlighted the parent link while selecting the drop down menu.

```
/* minimal styles for that navi */
.rmm {margin: 0 auto; float:right;}
.rmm ul {margin: 0; padding:0; list-style: none; position: relative;  background: #000;}
.rmm ul:after {content: ""; clear: both; display: block;}
.rmm ul li {float: left;}
.rmm ul li:hover {background: #202020;}
.rmm ul li:hover > ul {display: block;}
.rmm ul li:hover a{color: #fff;}
.rmm ul li a {color: #fff; display: block; text-decoration: none;}
.rmm ul li a:hover{color: #fff !important;}

.rmm ul ul {display: none; margin:0; padding: 0; position: absolute; top: 100%; }
.rmm ul ul li {float: none; position: relative;}
.rmm ul ul li a{color: #fff;}
.rmm ul ul li a:hover {background: #202020;}
.rmm ul ul ul {position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0; width: 100%;}
```

any one can help me out of this?

https://jsfiddle.net/ansarmon/qhuwxo5j/

Comment: I tried .rmm ul li a:focus{color: #fff ;}   but not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
.rmm ul li:hover a { color: #fff !important;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qhuwxo5j/2/

But actually you can better use one of ready-made solutions instead of your snippet.

Comment: thx, its very helpful, I will try to get a ready made option.